# How to erase Bash shell command history

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to clear recent inputs in terminal not cls or clear but when you press up or down. How do I clear this list so that when I rename sudo to nodood or something you cannot press up to view the new sudo perhaps my script will read input.

EDIT: Note pressing Ctrl + R in terminal will let you search history like
`history | grep searchQueryString` 
Another useful tip is 
`sudo !!` 
which re-executes last command with sudo prefixed

Comment: For complaints about the system use the meta site. For askubuntu that would be https://meta.askubuntu.com/  And it is of course an anti-spam measure. Please ONE question per topic. I answered the history part. The other one needs a separate question.

Comment: It is me that removed the rant in the question.

Comment: so after viewing the other post the history -c worked and about the mass renaming using mv *.* .*+datehashsuffix I will post a new question after having waited hours. And since I am not "well received"

Answer (score 7):

To clear your history use

```
history -c
```

Comment: +1 my friend!  Also, if you don't want `history -c` in your history put a space in front of the command.  =)

Comment: `history -c` will delete history of the present session of the terminal. For complete delete `rm ~/.bash_history`

Comment: He said 'recent' ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Deleting history**

- If you only want to delete a single command (eg: you have erroneous typed your password) type

  ```
   history -d <line number>
  ```
- In case you want to delete the entire history enter

  ```
   history -c; history -w
  ```
- History files can be found in your home directory. For bash this will be `.bash_history` and the temp files `.bash_history-xxxxxx.tmp`. Hence deleting these files would be another option.

To find out more about *history's hidden features* take a look at the [gnome bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html).